# Need your input Project Euler Q 8

Tags: c++, arrays

Is there a better way of doing this ?

http://projecteuler.net/problem=8

I added a condition to check if the number is >6 (Eliminates small products and 0's)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "bada.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int badanum[] { DATA };
    int pro=0,highest=0;
    for(int i=0;i<=996;++i)
    {
        if (badanum[i]>6 and badanum[i+1] > 6 and badanum[i+2] >6 and badanum[i+3]>6 and badanum[i+4]>6)
        {
            pro=badanum[i]*badanum[i+1]*badanum[i+2]*badanum[i+3]*badanum[i+4];
            if(pro>highest)
            {
                cout << pro << " " << badanum[i] << badanum[i+1] << badanum[i+2] << badanum[i+3] << badanum[i+4] << endl;
                highest = pro;
            }
            pro = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

bada.h is just a file containing the 1000 digit number.

```
#DEFINE DATA <1000 digit number>
```

http://projecteuler.net/problem=8

Comment: Wait, why would the extra condition be necessary? Also, as written, you're going off the end of the array. Finally, there's already another site for Code Reviews.

Comment: The `> 6` check makes your program wrong. You are not guaranteed to find 5 consecutive digits all greater than 6, and it is possible that the greatest product might involve a digit less than or equal to 6 even if there is a group of 5 digits all greater than 6.

Comment: 1000 digits means valid indices into `badanum` are 0 through 999. Your loop definitely goes out of range by reading `badanum[i+4]` with `i = 1000`.

Comment: @DennisMeng 5*5*5*5*5 is always less than 6*6*6*6*6 or 7*7*7*7*7
also this check also eliminates 0 products because the array has 0's too.

Comment: @DCoder thanks for pointing that out fixed that.Although i did get the correct answer without that.

Comment: @user2357112 check my reply to DennisMeng

Comment: @LulzAge: however, 9*9*9*9*2 is more than 6*6*6*6*6 .

Comment: @DCoder Hmmm..nice :D Never thought of it that way.I got the correct answer though.Maybe i should just check for number[i] > 0 so zero products are eliminated.

Comment: You don't need to eliminate zero products. Why would you? They'll either be less than some other product, in which case the normal logic for finding the maximum product will eliminate them, or they won't be less than some other product, in which case 0 is the maximum and you need to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

that if slows things down actually

- causes branching the parallel pipeline of CPU execution
- also as mentioned before it will invalidate the result
- does not matter that your solution is the same as it should be (for another digits it could not)

On algorithmic side you can do:

1. if you have fast enough division you can lower the computations number

   ```
   char a[]="7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450\0";

   int i=0,s=0,m=1,q;
   for (i=0;i<4;i++)
       {
       q=a[i  ]-'0'; if (q) m*=q;
       }
   for (i=0;i<996;i++)
       {
       q=a[i+4]-'0'; if (q) m*=q;
       if (s<m) s=m;
       q=a[i  ]-'0'; if (q) m/=q;
       }
   ```
2. also you can do a table for mul,div operations for speed (but that is not faster in all cases)

   ```
       int mul_5digits[9*9*9*9*9+1][10]={ 0*0,0*1,0*2, ... ,9*9*9*9*9/9 };
       int div_5digits[9*9*9*9*9+1][10]={ 0/0,0/1,0/2, ... ,9*9*9*9*9/9 };
       // so a=b*c; is rewritten by a=mul_5digits[b][c];
       // so a=b/c; is rewritten by a=div_5digits[b][c];
   ```

   - of course instead of **values 0*0** have to add **neutral value = 1** !!!
   - of course instead of **values i/0** have to add **neutral value = i** !!!

     ```
     int i=0,s=0,t=1;
     for (i=0;i<4;i++)
         {
         t=mul_5digits[t][a[i  ]-'0'];
         }
     for (i=0;i<996;i++)
         {
         t=mul_5digits[t][a[i+4]-'0'];
         if (s<t) s=t;
         t=div_5digits[t][a[i  ]-'0'];
         }
     ```

Run-time measurements on AMD 3.2GHz, 64bit Win7, 32 bit App BDS2006 C++:

```
0.022ms classic approach
0.013ms single mul,div per step (produce false outut if there is none product > 0 present)
0.054ms tabled single mul,div per step (is slower for my setup)
```

**PS.**

All code improvements should be measured so you see if you actually speed thing up or not.
Because what is faster for one compiler/platform/computer can be slower for another.
Use at least 0.1 ms resolution.
I prefer the use of RDTSC or PerformanceCounter for that.

Answer (score 0):

Except for the errors pointed out in the comments, that much multiplications aren´t necessary. If you start with the product of [0] * [1] * [2] * [3] * [4] for index 0, what would be the product starting at [1]? The old result divided by [0] and multiplied by [5]. One division and one multiplication could be faster than 4 multiplications

Comment: Except when [0] was `0`... since this is dealing with single-digit numbers, I really don't think this optimization will have any visible effect.

Comment: You are probably right that the effect would not be much with "only" 1000 single-digit numbers, and i´m not sure myself if it would be faster instead of slower that way. But it "could" be ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store all the digits at once. Just current five of them (use an array with cyclic overwriting), one variable to store the current problem result and one to store the latest multiplication result(see below). If the number of digits in the input will grow you won't get any troubles with memory.

Also you could have the check if the oldest read digit equals zero. If it is, than you will really have to multiply all the five current digits, but if not - a better way will be to divide previous multiplication result by the oldest digit and multiply it by the latest read digit.